# asp encoding in upload

Tags: utf-8, asp-classic, character-encoding, upload

I have this upload script that is messing everything with the encoding.

my form page has

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

and the form is

```
<form method='post' id='add_bula' name='add_bula' encType='multipart/form-data' acceptcharset='UTF-8' action='upload/file.asp'>
```

Any ideia why i get this "�" when i use this char "Ç" or "ã" for example?

the page that get the value is defined as

```
<%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" CODEPAGE="65001"%>
<%
Session.LCID = 2070
Response.ContentType = "text/html"
Response.AddHeader "Content-Type", "text/html;charset=UTF-8"
Response.CodePage = 65001
Response.CharSet = "UTF-8"
%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
<body>
```

Both pages are formated as "encoding in utf-8 without boom"

any ideia how to fix this?

thanks in advance

Comment: Just to confirm... you are seeing � in the uploaded file? What type of file is it?

Comment: Are you missing the `<html>` tag?

Comment: Im seing this in the input field where i give the file a new name, when i start the upload script and get Upload.Fields("File1").name it changes the ç ã caracters with � also it uploads the pdf file but in the name it does the same thing.  @Keith

Comment: Are you missing `CODEPAGE="65001"` in the form page?

Comment: @keith no codepage is in the form page also